# where I need to set my await compared to the code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

I can not really find out where along in the code I need to set my "await" so it run my code through to enable users to log in to the site.

Where the problem lies is where should I set my "await" when the user has success by log in to the site.

Error:

> 'UserLogin' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no
>   extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type
>   'UserLogin' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?)

```
[HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> login(UserLogin UserValue)
    {
        //Makes database access
        DataLinqDB db = new DataLinqDB();

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //Is this email and also downloads "salt" from the mail.
            var email = db.brugeres.FirstOrDefault(i => i.brugernavn == UserValue.Brugernavn);
            if (email != null)
            {
                //Makes password on the SHA256
                var pass = HelperClass.Helper.Hash.getHashSha256(UserValue.Brugernavn);

                //Checker up for a username and password match up with what you have written in. 
                //Checks also while on the salt as the few from the past to the fit with "email"
                var User = db.brugeres.FirstOrDefault(u => u.brugernavn == UserValue.Brugernavn && u.adgangskode == pass && u.salt == email.salt);
                if (User != null)
                {
                    .... code her ....
                    //Sending me over to the front. (the closed portion.)

                    await UserValue; //Error here!!!
                    return RedirectToAction("index");

                }
                else
                {
                    //Error - Invalid username and password do not match.
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unfortunately, it is wrong ..");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //Error - Invalid username do not match.
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "We could not find you!");
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
```

There where the fault lies here.

```
//Sending me over to the front. (the closed portion.)
await UserValue;//Error here!
return RedirectToAction("index");
```

Comment: In that logic branch, there doesn't appear to be anything to await.  `UserValue` is simply a `UserLogin` object and is not anything to await.

Comment: Actually there doesn't seem to be anything to await at all *as you have it written*, at least as far as we can tell from here.

Comment: @GlorinOakenfoot What do you completely with what you write? / Explain to me here?

Comment: You can only `await` something that is awaitable (has `GetAwaiter` method as suggested by error), usually a `Task`.

Comment: `await` waits for the result of an asynchronous function. `UserValue` is *definitely* not an asynchronous function, as it is data you're being supplied with. Usually async functions are marked with "Async" on the end of the name. You simply have nothing to await here, as there's nothing that's obviously an Async function.

Comment: @GlorinOakenfoot, `await` does NOT wait for the result of an asynchronous function. It has nothing to do with functions at all. `async` in method declaration allows to use `await` inside of it, that's all. You can `await` something that is not declared `async` just fine. You can await for any `Task` (and coincidentally all `async` methods return one, but it does not mean function is awaited, it's the `Task`)

Comment: @n0rd That's fine and all if you want to be pedantic. It's obvious this fellow doesn't understand what he's doing, so I was generalizing. It's obvious his data is not a task, so it need not apply. If you wish to enumerate everything about `await` further: every `async` method definitely does *not* return a `Task`. See `async void`s.

Comment: You explanation (`await UserValue` does not work because `UserValue` is not an asynchronous function) is wrong and might just cause more confusion. It cannot be awaited because it's not awaitable (i.e. not a `Task`). Well that sounds kind of fishy, I agree. And you are right, `async void` do exist, but they cannot be awaited and their use is generally discouraged. You have to be pedantic with programming, that's how computers work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UserValue` is your method parameter and why you want to await that ?

You might use `await` when you query your burgers table.You can use the `FirstOrDefaultAsync` method which is `awaitable`.

```
var email = await db.brugeres
                        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(i => i.brugernavn == UserValue.Brugernavn);
if (email != null)   
{
   //Continue with your other code (Password checking)
   //Make sure you remove the await UserValue line :)
}
```

`FirstOrDefaultAsync` is an extension method available in `System.Data.Entity` namespace, which is in `EntityFramework.dll`. The version i checked is the latest stable one as of today, Which is **EntityFramework 6.1.3** If you are not able to access this extenstion method, you might be using an old version of EF. Please update it to the latest stable from [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework).

Comment: Make error **'Table<brugere>' does not contain a definition for 'FirstOrDefaultAsync' and no extension method 'FirstOrDefaultAsync' accepting a first argument of type 'Table<brugere>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

Comment: Which version of EF are you using ? The FirstOrDefaultAsyc extension method is available in EF 6 onwards i think.

Comment: @JesperPetersen I was asking about Entity framework version, See my udpated answer.

Comment: oohhh okay :) and now it work for me!! :) Thanks for help!!, i hope u will giv me +1 :)